# Jenkins UI not displaying changes to configuration when using Nginx

Tags: linux, ubuntu, user-interface, nginx, jenkins

Very simple problem I have here with Jenkins on Ubuntu 20.04.1 and Nginx as a reverse proxy and I cannot figure out why it is doing it.

If I make any sort of changes (additions, deletions, edits) to any configuration file (*.xml, including jobs) via the UI (like on the /configure page for example) the changes are saved to disk properly (the actual .xml file changes) but the UI does not update unless I manually refresh the page, restart Jenkins, or use the "Reload Configuration From Disk" button.

I would expect Jenkins to **update the UI to reflect my changes as soon as I press save**, however **it does not**. If I visit a configuration again after making changes and saving, the UI shows **what it had previously** even though the .xml **file on disk was indeed modified**.

Hope someone has had a similar problem or at least can help in some way.

Note: Jenkins works as expected when Nginx is not being used as a reverse proxy for HTTPs. This problem only occurs when Nginx is being used.

Thanks

Comment: This is the intended behavior, that's why the "Reload Configuration from Disk" button exists. Jenkins has a current state of the configuration in memory and does not actively watch the config files for changes to reload them. There is a slim chance that there is a plugin out there doing what you want. Generally it is more advisable to use the UI anyway, since editing raw xml is cumbersome and doesn't really provide that much more control over the system.

Comment: @smelm Even with job configurations though? I don't see the advantage in not automatically reloading the configuration to reflect your changes so that you know your changes were actually made. Forcing users to have to click a button to reload the configuration EVERY time a change is made seems ridiculous.

Comment: like I said, it is probably not intended to be used that way. Jenkins leans more towards configuration via UI or via code (using pipelines and jobDSL). Stackoverflow is probably not the place for your problem, consider creating a feature request if it is something you feel strongly about.

Comment: Not sure if you read the question incorrectly or what because I just discovered that Jenkins does work as I have said I expected but only when our Nginx reverse proxy is not being used. When the Nginx proxy is being used to access Jenkins, the UI does not reflect changes made until the page is manually refreshed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Solved.

My Nginx configuration had an `expires` directive for all URIs of the Jenkins app which was instructing the client's browser to cache everything so that is the reason my global/job configuration changes were not being displayed in real time after saving them.

Lol.